# Borland C++ Typecast overrides - Why Ambiguity?

Tags: c++, casting, c++builder

I have the following Enum definition:

```
typedef enum MyEnumBase
{
  VALUE0 = 0,
  VALUE1,
  VALUE2,
  VALUE3
} MyEnum;
```

My class uses this enum the following way:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass (MyEnum initvalue) {enum1 = initvalue;};
  operator bool() {return (VALUE0 == enum1);};
  operator MyEnum() {return (enum1);};
private:
  MyEnum enum1;
};
```

With the main function:

```
int main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
  MyClass class1 = VALUE2;

  bool OK = (VALUE0 == class1);

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles with MS VC++ 2010 fine, but Borland XE2 and XE3 tells me the following:

```
[bcc32 Error] test.cpp(26): E2015 Ambiguity between 'operator MyClass::bool()' and 'operator MyClass::MyEnumBase()'
```

I guess it could be ambigous - but on the other hand the left side argument is of type MyEnum and it is kind of straight forward to make the enum cast rather than the boolean cast of the class. (As Visual Studio does)

If I swap the arguments (class1 == VALUE0) the problem still persists.

It is possible to modify the line to:

```
bool OK = (VALUE0 == (MyEnum)class1);
```

And it would compile, but in that case I would have to go over the whole giant project and "correct" every use of the class - which is not a very good idea since this is our "error variable", it is used excessively.

There must be a more elegant way making this compile. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on behalf of tebe:
Since I cannot post the conclusive answer that is more clear to me, I post my thoughts here:

Solution is to overload the global `operator ==` for MyEnum and MyClass arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Borland's compiler is clearly wrong here. So whatever you do has to be a workaround for the compiler bug, which makes it annoying, because there's not good "here's the elegant thing you should do" solution: the elegant thing is the thing you're currently doing, and it's triggering the bug. It's rare that there's more than one elegant solution to a problem.

So, the first thing to do is submit a bug report.

Then, one thing you could consider: do you need the conversion to the enum for anything aside from comparisons? If not (or if that case is rare), consider instead overloading the comparison between MyClass and MyEnum.

Comment: Overloading the comparison between the enum and the class sounds like a good plan. - But there is a but. In that case I would have to swap all the comparisons in my code, since the comparison is left-to-right. Therefore the compiler still wants to cast the class. 

On the other hand according to our coding standard (willingly not visible in the example ;) ) in case of comparisons the constant is the left side argument. - But if I do not find any way around I just have to swap the arguments.

Comment: @user2667821 - the overloaded function does not have to be a member function. `bool operator==(MyEnum, const MyClass&)` will work just fine. But see the answer by @DieterLücking.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid having a conversion operator and a non(!) explicit constructor taking the same type! explicit MyClass (MyEnum initvalue) enum1(initvalue) {} should fix it.

Comment: And to spell it out more clearly: the ambiguity is that `VALUE0 == class1` can be evaluated by converting `class1` to an enum (with the conversion operator) **or** by converting `VALUE0` to `MyClass` (with the constructor).

Comment: The line `bool OK = (false == class1);` yields the same problem - regardless that I have no constructor with boolean argument. Does borland interpret the `false` as int(0) as VALUE0 ?

Comment: On the other hand adding the operator `bool operator== (MyClass class2) {return enum1 == class2.enum1;};` does not solve the poblem.

Comment: I got it... Overloading the global operator== for my types solves the problem.